# Create layered navigation with custom productcollection magento2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, magento2, layered-navigation

I have a block class which has:

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\State $categoryFlatState,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,   
    ....
) {

    $this->_categoryHelper              = $categoryHelper;
    $this->_categoryFactory             = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_collectionFactory           = $collectionFactory;
    $this->categoryFlatConfig           = $categoryFlatState;
    $this->_productCollectionFactory    = $productCollectionFactory;  
    parent::__construct($context);
    ....
}
```

and a function of...

```
public function getProductCollection($childId)
{
    $categoryId = $childId;
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('special_price');
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
}
```

How do I use this production collection to create a layered navigation which uses attributes available for the products returned, and then be able to filter through with those.

Due to the nature of the site, I have to loop through this X amount of times on a category page, as I am getting products of each subcategory on this page in a certain way due to the design.

So in my template for E.G I have:

```
`$products= $this->getProductCollection($idhere);
foreach ($getmeprods as $products):?>
... looping through data
<?php endforeach;?>
```

`
Any help would be appreciate but I am rather boggled here!

Comment: Any solution you got @RForster